# Get distinct from1 table and from another one all data

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, filter

i have a filter product functionality with `ajax and php`, my html looks like that:

```
<div class="sidebar-widget color-widgets">
<h6>FILTER BY COLOR </h6>
<ul>
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" class="common_selector color"  id="red" value="red" >
        <label for="red">red</label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" class="common_selector color"  id="grey" value="grey" >
        <label for="grey">grey</label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" class="common_selector color"  id="blue" value="blue" >
        <label for="blue">blue</label>
    </li>
</ul>
```

My `mysql` table for products looks like that:

```
|id|name|id_cat|price|status|
```

Second table colors which is related to table `products`:

```
|id|id_product|color_name|
```

When i insert a product in database can put some colors to one product but is stored in another table.

My `ajax` looks like that:

```
if(isset($_POST["action"])){
    $query = "
    SELECT * FROM products WHERE status = 1 AND id_cat = 81";
}

if(isset($_POST["color"])){
    $color_filter = implode("','", $_POST["color"]);
    $query .= "
     AND color IN('".$brand_filter."')
    ";
}
```

On this functionality i want when user click o color red,blue to go on database and select distinct from colors table and retrive data to user, i am stuck at this because i dont know how i can make this, second solution what i was thinking to insert color `id` into table products in a new column named `color_id`, but then i need to explode by `,` and fetch it.

Before posting about help here to understand what solution to aproach i used google but kinda not find what i really need to understand how i can make this or maybe to understand it.
Thanks.

EDIT: When page is loaded is retriving all products for user when user check 1 or more checkboxes is going on my `php` file and fetch products based by colors checked and retrive back to user products with their colors checked.

Comment: I can't understand what you're trying to do. When the user clicks on red and blue, and I presume submits the form, what data do you want to be retrieved? It might help if you include that in your question.

Comment: Done, is just filtering products by color checked by user and retrive to him.

Comment: Can a product have multiple colours?

Comment: Yes, product can have multiple colors.

Comment: Would there be a separate record in the `products` table for each colour of a project? Or are you storing all the different colours of a product in one record?

Comment: On table products i dont wanted to insert colors because a product can have multiple colors and i did a new table with colors and when a product is inserted into products is taking his id and put it into colors table with color inserted by administrator, administrator can put multiple colors for each product. So what i am stuck is the query select where i need to get all products and colors selected by user.

Comment: There is a lot incorrect here.  Going to try and point you in the right direction.  If you get stuck again, post another question.  The column "color" does not exist in either table, but it for sure does not exist in the products table which is what your query is referencing.  You need to join the two tables in your query on the primary and foreign keys.  Also, just a note...The variable name in your "IN" is not correct...You are defining $color_filter and trying to use $brand_filter.

Comment: Thanks JOIN two tables is exactly what i need, thank you!